# Best practice for waiting on nested thens

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I have a scenario where I have three tables in a PostgreSQL database, `users`, `orgs`, and `users_orgs`, which links the first two.  I use Express and `pg` to handle the DB calls. Now, if I want to, say, attach a list of `org` records to a `user` record, I want to perform one query for the `user` record, one for all of the `users_orgs` associated with that `user`, and then one for each of those records to get the `orgs`.

When I do this, I end up with something like

```
const user_query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=${id}`;
pg.query(user_query)
  .then((user_result) => {
    const users = user_result.rows;
    users.map((user) => {
      user.orgs = [];
      const users_orgs_query = `SELECT org_id FROM users_orgs WHERE user_id = '${user.id}'`;
      pg.query(users_orgs_query)
        .then((users_orgs_result) => {
           return new Promise((res, rej) => {
             const users_orgs = users_orgs_result.rows;
             let c = 0;
             users_orgs.map((user_org) => {
               const orgs_query = `SELECT * FROM orgs WHERE id = '${user_org.org_id}'`;
               pg.query(orgs_query)
                 .then((r) => {
                   const orgs = r.rows;
                   user.orgs.push(orgs[0]);
                   c += 1;
                   if (c >= users_orgs.length) {
                     res(user);
                   }
                 });
             });
          });
        })
        .then((u) => {
          res.status(200).json(u);
        });
    });
```

Now, this works, but I feel confident that counting into my `map` is not a good idea. Clearly, I could replace the inner `map` with a `for` loop and just count and resolve the promise that way as well, but that feels like something I would do in C (which is where I normally work) and that feels like cheating.

However, I need the resolve to happen after the last element maps because otherwise, I will respond to the request before adding all the orgs to the user. Surely this is not uncommon, but I feel like I am not seeing anything related when I search, which leads me to believe that I'm searching poorly and/or thinking about this all wrong.

There may even be a SQL query-based solution to this type of thing, and that's great, but I would still be curious if there is a way to wait for a loop of nested promises to resolve in an elegant manner.

To make it clear, the actual question is, is there a way to know that all of the inner promises have been resolved without having to actually count them all, as I do here?

Comment: oh god, please use await & async...

Comment: @ChangAlex Should it make a difference? With `pg` would I have to assign each call to a variable with `await`? Sorry, like I said, JS isn't my everyday.

Comment: I'll give you an async version, wait.

Comment: Should `result.rows` be `user_result.rows`?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes it should - typo was in the example here but not in my code.

Comment: After the `orgs_query`, you do `user.orgs.push(orgs[0]);`. Does that mean that you only want the first item in `orgs` to be added to your user's `orgs` array?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes that was right, only the first record - `id` is the primary key so there will only ever be (at most) one such record. Is there a better way to get it than looking at the first spot in the return array?

Comment: No, this way is fine. Just making sure it does what you intended it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for all the promises to finish by using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). This function accepts an array of promises and returns a `Promise` by itself, which will resolve when all given promises have successfully been resolved.

Use this is in combination [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of the array to return an array of promises.

```
async function getUsersWithOrgs(id) {
  const user_query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=${id}`;
  const { rows: users } = await pg.query(user_query)

  return Promise.all(users.map(async user => {
    const users_orgs_query = `SELECT org_id FROM users_orgs WHERE user_id = '${user.id}'`;
    const { rows: users_orgs } =  await pg.query(users_orgs_query);

    const orgs = await Promise.all(users_orgs.map(async user_org => {
      const orgs_query = `SELECT * FROM orgs WHERE id = '${user_org.org_id}'`;
      const { rows: orgs } = await pg.query(orgs_query);
      return orgs[0];
    }));
    
    return {
      ...user,
      orgs
    };
  }));
}
```

```
getUsersWithOrgs(id).then(users => {
  res.status(200).json(users);
});
```

Comment: This is very much what I had in mind, and I've learned quite a bit while researching your answer, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `async`, `await` and for the inner promises you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

`await`ing individually query will be un-optimal.

You can structure your code like (taking the innermost query as an example):

```
const orgs_query = `SELECT * FROM orgs WHERE id = '${user_org.org_id}'`;
await Promise.all(user_orgs.map((user_org) => {
    pg.query(orgs_query)
        .then((r) => {
           const orgs = r.rows;
           user.orgs.push(orgs[0]);
        });
}));

// Return the response as you like from the users object
```

The `pq.query` returns a `Promise` from the mapped function. The outer `Promise.all` will collect these promises and `await` till all of them return.

This way you don't need to nest.

Answer (score 0):

Async version, btw your code is a little complex, so maybe not work.
If not working, please comment:

```
const user_query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=${id}`;
const user_result = await pg.query(user_query);
const users = result.rows;
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const user = users[i];
    user.orgs = [];
    const users_orgs_query = `SELECT org_id FROM users_orgs WHERE user_id = '${user.id}'`;
    const users_orgs_result = await pg.query(users_orgs_query);
    const users_orgs = users_orgs_result.rows;
    for (let j = 0; j < users_orgs.length; j++) {
        const user_org = users_orgs[j];
        const orgs_query = `SELECT * FROM orgs WHERE id = '${user_org.org_id}'`;
        const r = await pg.query(orgs_query);
        const orgs = r.rows;
        user.orgs.push(orgs[0]);
        if (c == users_orgs.length - 1) {
            res.status(200).json(u);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Certainly more readable :-)  Although now I guess you can drop the dummy counter `c` and just compare against `j`.  It still feels a little non-javascript to me to not have a wait to wrap up the entire map in something that will only resolve once all the inner promises resolve, no?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: BTW your map function is just a forEach because that actually doesn't return anything,
so I replaced it with for loop for await.

Comment: If you mean in the `for` loop, then you notice that you compare the value of `c` with `users_orgs.length`, but the way you have it you can just see if `j >= users_orgs.length - 1`.

Comment: I think that check is unnecessary.
I just help you with part async, If you want to optimize your code.
I think you can do it yourself.

Comment: If you want check if it last element just do.
`if(j == users_orgs.length-1) res(user);`

Comment: Ah sorry, that was what I was actually asking about. I must not have been very clear about it. What I intended to ask was, how do you keep track of when all of the inner promises have been resolved without having to literally count them?

Comment: Oh I know, let me check again

Comment: @TrivialCase ok recheck my anwser.

Comment: And I am confused with your `res.status(200).json(u);` because you should only send that once and in your code, the map function may be called many times.

Comment: In this case I am querying the `users` table on the primary key, so I will only ever get back one record.

Comment: Oh I see, then my code is okay for now, go test.

Comment: And If only one record you can just use `arr[0]`